# Django rest framework, Create predefined authentaction

Tags: python, authentication, django-rest-framework

I have a RestAPI created with the Django rest framework.

I need to create authentication for the API that will allow access on a predefined by the admin user name and password.

IS it possible with DRF?

Also, I want that every object created will be assigned to the user (which I guess includes using some kind of decorator in the view?)

Answer (score 1):

- DRF already ships with [BasicAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication), which has the user send their username + password with each request. That sounds like what you want. (If it isn't, you can write your own Authentication class.)
- To automagically assign created objects to the authenticated user, use [CurrentUserDefault](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) on the relevant User field.